# React keeps catching Network Error! when trying to get data from localhost:8080

Tags: reactjs, go, axios

I have a golang server listening on port 8080. I am trying to get data from it (curl does get it successfully) but my React application keeps catching error on Axios Get, it displays "Network Error!".
I tried "rejectUnauthorized: false" to ignore SSL errors, I tried "AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"}," on my server to allow requests from my React application.
I am still getting the error, the Firefox Network tab is showing: "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long".

My React code looks like this:

```
 //Action creators
 export const fetchDataRequest = () => ({
      type: FETCH_REQUEST
 });

 export const fetchDataSuccess = (elements) => ({
       type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
       payload: {elements}
 });

 export const fetchDataError = (error) => ({
       type: FETCH_ERROR,
       payload: {error}
 });

 export function fetchDataWithRedux() {
       return function (dispatch) {
         dispatch(fetchDataRequest());
         axios.get("https://localhost:8080/data")
      .then((response) =>{
         dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(response.json));
          console.log(response);
       })
      .catch (error => {
           dispatch(fetchDataError(error))
           console.log(error.message);
       })
     }
  }
```

My Main.go looks like this:

```
func main() {
    //Call the NewRouter function defined in route pkg
    route := n.NewRouter()

    //convert h.handlers to a http.HandlerFunc
    JSONHandler := http.HandlerFunc(h.JsonHandler)
    DATAHandler := http.HandlerFunc(h.NixDataHandler)

    //Give the handle to the created router
    http.Handle("/", route)
    route.Handle("/nix", h.JsonHandlerWrapper(JSONHandler))
    route.Handle("/data", h.JsonHandlerWrapper(DATAHandler))

    //Call function to fetch data from nix.org periodically
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    go func() {
        <- timer.C
        //call function
        data.GetNixData()
    }()

    //Handling CORS requests
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST"},
    })

    //Start listening on port 8080
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", c.Handler(route)))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Axios Get localhost without https, like this `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/data")`.

To configure golang https server need use `http.ListenAndServeTLS`, in you case it configured for http by this `http.ListenAndServe`.

Take a look at official docs https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS

Comment: [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for the OP.

Comment: To give some more context: `https` and `http` are different (but related) protocols. `http` is plaintext and if you run a network sniffer like Wireshark, you can actually read your messages being sent. `https` combines http messages with an encryption protocol called `tls`. `tls` and therfor `https` requires you to create security objects (private key, public cert) in order for it to work. If you look at Wireshark while sending these messages you could not read them.

Comment: Actually it was a typo. I still don't know why I wrote "https" in my url but thanks for pointing it out.